# Basic concept/principle of ECommerce Site

Tags: php, e-commerce, phppgadmin

Is there any short tutorial which explain the basic principles/concept and Database design of an Ecommerce Website?

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for a technical solution for building an Ecommerce Website ? I'd advise you to use a builtin solution designed for this purpose, here are some best-of :

- http://woork.blogspot.com/2009/01/8-interesting-cms-for-e-commerce.html
- http://www.ilovecolors.com.ar/ecommerce-cms-open-source-commercial/
- (if you choose to use Joomla!) http://www.web3mantra.com/2011/01/24/20-joomla-ecommerce-templates/

Were you looking for tips ?

- http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/08/15-common-mistakes-in-e-commerce-design-and-how-to-avoid-them/

Regards,

Max